# How to make PC shut down automatically once i log out of windows terminal server?

Tags: lubuntu

We use Lubuntu 15.04 to connect to Windows terminal server with `rdesktop` software.  When I turn on my pc, I automatically connect to win terminal server and can log in with my account without seeing Lubuntu gui in the screen. But when I log out, It returns to Lubuntu interface. I would like the computer to automatically turn of once I log out. Because I want Lubuntu to run in background without being seen during basic usage.

Can you help us with this matter?

`/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99x11-common_start`

```
#!bin/sh
xmms &
xterm &

rdesktop -f 192.168.0.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rdesktop` does not run in the background, when it ends you can run the `poweroff` command by adding this to the it to the end of the `99x11-common_start` file.

However, you need to be root to run it, so typically you would need to add:

```
 sudo /sbin/poweroff
```

To avoid typing a password for this one command, create a file, `/etc/sudoers.d/myname` where `myname` is your user name, with the line:

```
myname ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
```

Ensure the file is only writable by root. Be careful when editing sudo files: always ensure you have a root shell in some other window, and use `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myname`.

Answer (score 0):

If command is local, this is better to send something like this:

Reboot:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot boolean:true
```

Shutdown:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff boolean:true
```

To avoid messing with sudoers

This is basicly the gui poweroff or reboot command under icons

I have write a Qt/c++ shutdown timer for my "movie - fall asleep in 5 min" a while ago.